# How to get dual sim card Phone Numbers in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Need to get phone numbers if the device has a dual SIM Card. There is solution for get primary mobile number. I could not find dual phone number from the device.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are some plugins that could do this kind of functionality. Some of it are the following:

- [mobile_number](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_number)
- [sim_data](https://pub.dev/packages/sim_data)

But ATM, both plugins could only work in Android.

Comment: Did it help? Both of then doesn't work on me