# Get dual sim device mobile number from android programatically

Tags: android, flutter

How to get dual sim device mobile number from android programatically. I am getting only the default sim number. Is there any way to get both sim mobile numbers. I tried with below code.But getting only default sim with slot 0

```
SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
SubscriptionInfo simInfo = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(simSlot);0/1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get dual sim card Phone Numbers in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561916/how-to-get-dual-sim-card-phone-numbers-in-flutter)

Comment: Am getting only number of first sim slot, which is default one.